# What does it mean to have an observation variance of zero when fitting a model using StructTS in R?

Tags: r, time-series, state-space-models

I'm using the `StructTS()` function in R to fit 50 structural time series models (state-space models) on 50 univariate time series. I'm using the "trend" specification with a deterministic drift term (i.e. `sts = StructTS(x = y, type = "trend", fixed = c(NA, 0, NA))`).

This model can be represented by the following equations. First, the latent state equation describes the longer term, underlying process of the time series:
$$
x_{t+1} = x_t + d + \eta_t
$$
with $\eta_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2_{\eta})$.

Second, the observation equation adds the observation level disturbance/error term to the state term to model the observations, $y_t$:

$$
y_t = x_t + \epsilon_t
$$
with $\epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma^2_{\epsilon})$

Around a fifth of the models I fit estimate an observation variance ($\sigma^2_\epsilon$) value of 0, which apparently is common according to the `StructTS()` help page:

> Optimization of structural models is a lot harder than many of the references admit. For example, the AirPassengers data are considered in Brockwell & Davis (1996): their solution appears to be a local maximum, but nowhere near as good a fit as that produced by StructTS. It is quite common to find fits with one or more variances zero, and this can include $\sigma^2_\epsilon$.

However, the way that I'm interpreting what this parameter represents is not compatible with a $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ of zero. From my understanding, $\epsilon_t$ represents measurement or sampling error. I would expect all of my time series to have some sampling error and don't understand why $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ would ever be estimated as 0. Am I misinterpreting what $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ means? Does a $\sigma^2_\epsilon$ of 0 indicate model misspecification? An explanation of how to interpret a $\sigma^2_\epsilon = 0$ would be much appreciated.